# Can't see implementation of protected abstract functions in Android package

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop

I have been going over the android package a bit. I am using sdk 30 and for example in *SensorManager.java* there is a function

```
protected abstract List<Sensor> getFullSensorList();
```

Now, even though it is not implemented, *getFullSensor();* list is used in

```
    public List<Sensor> getSensorList(int type)
```

Can someone explain me how is this possible? Also how can I see the implementation of *getFullSensorList();* ?
I understand that I can implement the method via a subclass and that they use *@hide* annotation in the comment because they don't want me to use it in their API, but I just want to see the read-only implementation. How does this work in here if it is not implemented since it's abstract though I am using it to for, for example read sensor data and similar?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android per se. Not only that method is abstract, but the whole class. So there are definitely SUBCLASSES of the SensorManager somewhere. And at RUNTIME, you are dealing with instances of those SUBCLASSES. So when code is running, the object on which you are calling getFullSensorList() is a subclass that has the method, and that will return a valid result when invoked.

Comment: Now the problem might be: if the Android folks want to "hide" those subclasses from you for some reason ... you might have a hard time. So it kind of depends ... if you have the Android source code locally available, and maybe even setup in your IDE ... then you can use the capabilities of your IDE to identify subclasses.